# Pyspark - limit files size when writing dataframe to json

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using `pyspark v3`. I'm using the following code to write a dataframe to a json file, How can we limit the size of the output files to 100MB ?

```
    data_frame\
        .coalesce(1)\
        .write\
        .mode("overwrite")\
        .option("ignoreNullFields", "false")\
        .format("json")\
        .save(path)
```

Comment: Just a bit note, it may be useful for someone, in my case .. I'm runnig an AWS Glue job with 10xWorkers it gives files with 160MB but when using 20xWorkers it gives 80MB

Answer (score 1):

Spark has an option to limit the number of rows per file and thus the file size using the `spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile` configuration (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)).

You can try and estimate how many rows there should be in order to have a limit of around 100MB (it's an estimation as this depends on the format and the data).

Comment: changing `spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile`will impact the reading capacity too ! thus it'll impact the performance

Comment: @Smaillns the read path is not affected by `spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile`.
The number of partitions for the read path is determined by bin packing. You can see some more details [here](https://dzone.com/articles/guide-to-partitions-calculation-for-processing-dat)